# Animate viewscreen over a large image with gimp

Tags: animation, png, jpeg, gif, gimp

I would like to create an animated view of a large image so it is viewed partially while the viewport moves. Say have an image 3000x2000 px, create a view 1000x2000px that moves slowly up and down. How could I achieve this with gimp? Many thanks,
filimon

Answer (score 0):

You can use GAP, the GIMP Animation Plug-Ins. They allow you to animate various aspects of layers, for example their position and size. See https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Using_GAP/ for a tutorial.

Most likely, you will use the Move Path plug-in. Its documentation is available at https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp-gap/tree/docs/reference/txt/plug-in-gap-move-path.txt (and maybe someone can create a better answer from this :)